# Notepad++ RegEx does not work with min and max occurence

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I want to find two or more (max 9) white-space characters and replace it with newlines.

My RegEx syntax is as follows:

```
[\s]{2,9}
```

However, Notepad++'s RegEx doesn't seem to work with curly braces. When I use plugin RegEx helper, it highlights proper values, using above syntax. It doesn't, however, replace the found values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found no reference to curly-based occurence numbering in Notepad++ regexp documentation.

Then you should to it the hard way:

```
\s\s\s?\s?\s?\s?\s?\s?\s?
```

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++ does not support explicit quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924380/259953):

> You can, however, use the following quantifiers:
>
> - `k*`, which is equivalent to `k{0,}`.
> - `k+`, which is equivalent to `k{1,}`.
> - `k?`, which is equivalent to `k{0,1}`.

Comment: No, `\s` is "always" a character class. So `[\s]` is the same as `\s`.